# In prestashop module. How to display content in center column?

Tags: module, prestashop

I'm trying to write a CMS news module to PrestaShop 1.5. And I cannot find a way nor a hook to display content in center column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own php and tpl file to make your own pages and display content in center column. More info can be found in [official guide on how-to create a module for Prestashop 1.5](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module#CreatingaPrestaShopmodule-Displayingcontent)

Comment: This is some way, but isn't it breaking the MVC and hook system?

Comment: but as I understand you're going to create your pages from scratch, hooks is the way to add/change existing prestashop functionality or for example display info on product/category etc. pages

Comment: Well, not exactly from a scratch. I'm trying do to do a simple news module that will display news in center column. It should work for every theme in PrestaShop 1.5. So it is not from a scratch.

Comment: Yes, I got it. You will use left and right column from every theme and display your own content in center part, that's what I meant. My suggestion for you to google Blog or News Prestashop extension (there are some free out there) and take a look how this was done by other developers

Comment: http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/139638-module-free-blog-module-a-usefull-prestashop-module/   (I haven't used it nor made a code review)